# Cannot remove DevonThink Pro from menu bar

Tags: menu-bar, macos

I installed DEVONthink Pro, then uninstalled by removing the App from the Applications dir, but I can not get rid of the icon/menu in the menu bar.

[image]

I've removed every file anywhere that has the name 'devon', but the think just will not go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu you are seeing is actually the AppleScript system menu. It gives you a handy way to launch applications when you're in an app.

To turn it off:

1. Select the option in the menu Open AppleScript Editor.app
2. Open the Preferences menu
3. Unselect the Show Script Menu [image]